# Radeon proprietary driver and Upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

I upgrade to 16.04 and a had manually install radeon proprietary driver on 14.04. After upgrade a can only go to console mode (alt+F1). I uninstall proprietary driver as explained in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx

But when I reinstall **xserver-xorg-core** it says that is unable to download package. I do

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And radeon command is not find.

But it's not working after reboot.
Any advice ?

update
I try

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

but there a trouble with dependency xorg-video-abi-20

Comment: The question is not clear. What is "radeon proprietary driver"? If it is "fglrx", then it is not supported in 16.04. You do not need to install any drivers in 16.04.

Comment: yes but after the install it keeps fglrx and that not working. So I try to reinstall standard driver.

Comment: Why not just remove fglrx?

Comment: I do but now I try to install drivers because It doesn't work after uninstall and reboot

Comment: The fglrx had been manually installed with ati site binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install aptitude to solve the problem it downgrade some packages that a have in raring to older version in xenial. Now a get a graphical loggin screen but it freezes....